# JavaScript (jQuery) does not react anymore after I have changed the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 links:

```
<span id="a-start-container">
<a id="a-start" href="#">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-play inner-circle-color"></i>
</a>
</span>

<span id="a-stop-container">
<a id="a-stop" href="#">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-play inner-circle-color"></i>
</a>
</span>
```

When I click on the first one (a-start) I'm disabling it by removing the `<a>` element and at the same time I enable the second one (a-stop) by adding the `<a>` element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#a-start").click(function(e){
  $("#a-stop-container").html("<a id='a-stop' href=''><i class='fa fa-fw fa-stop inner-circle-color'></a>");
  $("#a-start-container").html("<i class='fa fa-fw fa-play inner-circle-color'>");
})
});
```

When I click on the second one (a-stop) I'm disabling it by removing the `<a>` element and at the same time I enable the first one (a-start) by adding the `<a>` element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#a-stop").click(function(e){
  $("#a-start-container").html("<a id='a-start' href=''><i class='fa fa-fw fa-play inner-circle-color'></a>");
  $("#a-stop-container").html("<i class='fa fa-fw fa-stop inner-circle-color-off'>");
  })
});
```

The problem is that it works only for the first click. For example I click on the first one (a-start), then it changes a-start and enables a-stop. But then, when I click on a-stop, JavaScript does not react anymore. The same situation the other way round. Both work fine until the `<a>` element gets changed - then I have to reload the page to get it run again.

There is no information in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked console

Comment: how are the click eventListeners defined?

Comment: you should change it to `on` instead of `click`. What you are doing is replacing entire DOM content on which handler/listener is registered and thus it dont get registered on DOM change which is happening after first event.

Comment: FYI You don't have the closing parenthesis on your `.click()` method

Comment: Can you post you css?

Comment: @Luca I'm sorry I'm new to JavaScript, I'm afraid I haven't created any - should I?

Comment: Reference the duplicate post to learn how to create delegate event bindings to handle for future elements created/modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should consider changing it to `on` instead of `click` based on the pattern that you are using. Usage of `on` can be found her: http://api.jquery.com/on/

What you are doing is replacing entire DOM content on which handler/listener is registered and thus it dont get re-registered on DOM change which is happening after first `click` event.

However what seemed like you only wanted to toggle class-name and text of the link which should have been handled via http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ which would be more appropriate.

Comment: That's not enough information. You seem to imply that the OP should use event delegation, but that means `.on` has to be used in a specific way. Merely replacing `.click` with `.on` won't solve the problem.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I changed it to `$("#a-start-container").on("click", "#a-start", function(e){}` and it works.